# Where can I see the most recent edit history of a user in DOORS?

Tags: ibm-doors

## Background

Inside DOORS, I am trying to find a specific module that I was editing yesterday.  However, I forgot the specific module that I edited.

## Question

Is there an option in the top level of DOORS that allows you to look at the most recent edit history of a specific user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know- there is not.

History is stored with the item modified (module, object, etc)- unless you have some very extensive logging turned on, there won't be a record independent of those that links your username to them.

If you are sure you were the last person to modify that module, you could do a recursive search on module properties that checks the last modified by module level attribute (you do not need to open a module to check module level attributes)